# Windows Server 2003 Remote Desktop Login Slowness

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

When I do an initial login to Windows Server 2003 after a reboot it hangs on blank desktop (no icons or taskbar) for 15-20 seconds. This doesn't happen if I close the RDP window and login to the same session. But if I login to a second session it hangs again.

Any idea why the initial login hangs for so long before displaying anything but desktop background?

Comment: Same here. Iappens rarely. It seems like for example a lost IP packet that then hangs the connection until the TCP stack decides to resend it or something like that. I can so far not put a finger on it - happens on many machines, rarely, but it seems not to be a driver / hardware issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a disconnected mapped network drive from an old subnet that for some reason was trying to reconnect to whenever I logged in. Manually 'disconnecting' it so it no longer tried to reconnect made the problem go away.

I found this using Process Monitor when I noticed that the first thing it did on the session when it "caught up" was to `RegCloseKey HKCU\Network\y`.

Thanks for all the good suggestions hopefully this will help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the event log for hints? Is this a domain controller? If not, is the server in the same network as your domain server(s) or on a low-bandwith connection?

Or maybe there is a program starting (antivirus?) and delaying the logon process.

Comment: Nothing in the event log. It did have an error about printer drivers but I disabled sharing printer and that didn't fix the delay. Not a domain controller. No domain, just workgroup with local users. High bandwidth and everything else is fast. Checked `msconfig` and elsewhere and nothing appears to be running to delay it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe this (though that problem was not only login related - all was slow...): http://blog.tmcnet.com/blog/tom-keating/microsoft/remote-desktop-slow-problem-solved.asp

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts:

o Does it happen if you leave the server for 5 mins following the reboot?  i.e.: allow any service / driver issues to timeout.

o Try logging on as another admin account and delete your [original] user profile.  See if it still happens.

o Does it happen if you use the console session (session #0), i.e.: MSTSC /V: /ADMIN   (or /CONSOLE if you're running XP pre-SP3).

o Logon as an admin, with a "working" session.  Use SysInternals ProcessExplorer to monitor the activity of a "duff" logon.  Look for CPU intensive processes, Etc.

o Use SysInternals AutoRuns to see what's running on Logon.  Try disabling things and see whether the situation improves.

Answer (score 1):

Desktop Background may be downloading when you log on (is it a bitmap not jpg), anyway
edit your RDP connection and set your experience (from the Experience tab) to 28.8Kbps - this turns off all the unnecessary options that increases network traffic (including downloading the Desktop Background) - remember to save this setting in the General tab.